# Repository.save() does not persist entities with CascadeType = all

Tags: spring, jpa, cascading

I want to add cascading to the entities in our database. I added `@OneToMany(mappedBy = "exercise",cascade = CascadeType.ALL, fetch = FetchType.EAGER)`
to the parent relation to test how this works.
However, the child entity does not seem to be saved at all when I save the parent entity.
When searching online for answers, I found that session apparently has methods to save and/or persist entities. The problem is that I get utterly confused by how sessions work and no attempt has been successful. My question is, does cascading work with `repository.save()`? And if not, what is the best way to do this? Thanks in advance.

parent entity:

```
@Getter
@Setter
@Entity
@Builder
@NoArgsConstructor
@AllArgsConstructor
public class Module {

    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.IDENTITY)
    private Long id;

    @Builder.Default
    @OneToMany(mappedBy = "module", fetch = FetchType.EAGER, cascade = CascadeType.ALL, orphanRemoval = true)
    @Fetch(value = FetchMode.SUBSELECT)
    @JsonBackReference
    private List<Exercise> exercises = new ArrayList<>();
    
    public void saveExercise(Exercise exercise) {
        int index = exercises.indexOf(exercise);
        if (index == -1) {
            exercises.add(exercise);
        } else {
            exercises.set(index, exercise);
        }
    }
    // methods
}
```

Child entity

```
@Getter
@Setter
@Entity
@Builder
@NoArgsConstructor
@AllArgsConstructor
public class Exercise {

    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.IDENTITY)
    private Long id;

    @NonNull
    @ManyToOne
    @JsonManagedReference
    private Module module;
    
    // methods
}
```

Module service

```
@Transactional
@Service
public class ModuleService {

public void saveModule(Module module) {
        moduleRepository.save(module);
    }
}
```

Exercise service:

```
@Transactional
@Service
public class ExerciseService {
    public void saveExercise(Exercise exercise) {
        // Get parent in relationship
        Module module = exercise.getModule();

        // Update parent
        module.saveExercise(exercise);

        // Save parent
        moduleService.saveModule(module);
    }
    public Exercise getExerciseById(Long exerciseId) {
        return exerciseRepository.findById(exerciseId).orElseThrow();
    }

}
```

Test:

```
    @Test
    public void testSaveDeleteExercise() {
        Exercise exercise = Exercise.builder().id(101L).module(module).build();

        exerciseService.saveExercise(exercise);

        assertThat(exerciseService.getExerciseById(exercise.getId())).isEqualTo(exercise);
}
```

with exception:

```
java.util.NoSuchElementException: No value present
```

Comment: In test you are trying to save exercise, instead of module, as you write in question. Did you copy wrong example? Also, the exception you is probably from `getExerciseById`. Have you check for any exceptions during save?

Comment: when you save a module, you also save the exercises that belong to this module (when cascading is enabled) right? the `saveExercise` method in exerciseService saves the exercise through the module.

Comment: Yes, it should. I am not sure about setting exercise ID when you have `@GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.IDENTITY)`. This means that ID is generated in DB, such as auto increment column. Have you try not setting ID on exercise and module, because it will be received from DB? Or remove @GeneratedValue if you want to set ID from code.